# Keep a separate "filtered" version of a Backbone.js Collection - or is there another way?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backgrid

Using Backgrid to show tables with two backbone Collections (CollectionA and CollectionB) which could contain "large" data (maybe several thousand models).  Now that I've got Backgrid handling the two collections nicely, I need to add a checkbox that will cause a filter to be applied to the Collection.  The filter involves some calculating; its not just like color == "red".

I could create a second, filtered copy of each Collection (backgrid displays a collection), but I'd rather not have to add listeners to handle new data that comes in from time to time.  Also, memory, copy time etc because the filtered version isn't necessarily small.

Qt has a thing called a ProxyModel which (in my case) would look like a Collection (so Backgrid could connect to it) but really goes between the Collection and Backgrid (or any other View).  It would only give the Models that make it through the filter and it would take CRUD instruction.  Is there such a thing in Backbone?

Each Model is less than 1K of content (not counting the structural data in the Model/Collection) so are my copy time/memory concerns unneeded?  I don't think so, any thoughts would be appreciated!

Comment: can u plz tell how did u managed to handle two backbone collections?

Comment: I created a calculated field in the model.  See http://kilon.org/blog/2012/02/backbone-calculated-fields/

Then I did filtering based on the calculated field.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11886628/backbone-js-correct-way-of-filtering-a-collection

Comment: ok thanks n can u tell how can i display the foreign key table fields in my grid?