# Backbone.js Sorting a filtered collection?

Tags: sorting, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events, backbone.js-collections

I am a backbone newbie and this is my first attempt at sorting and filtering a collection and would really appreciate any help. I have a Backbone View that displays a collection of models which when loaded are sorted in reverse date order using the collections comparator. This collection has methods which allow for the sorting to be changed by setting the comparator to a different value (company) and calling the sort method on the collection.

The collection also has a method that filters the collection and returns a new filtered collection. The problem I am having is that I cannot use the sort methods on the new filtered collection.

The Collection

```
var Tickets = Backbone.Collection.extend({
model: TicketModel,
url: '/tickets',

comparator: function(a,b) {
    if(a.get('date') < b.get('date')) {
        return 1;   
    } else if(b.get('date') > a.get('date')){
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
},

byFilter: function(key, value){
    filtered = this.filter(function(data){
        return data.get(key) === value;
    });
    return new Tickets(filtered);
},

byDate: function() {
    this.comparator = function(a, b) {
        if(a.get('date') < b.get('date')) {
            return 1;   
        } else if(b.get('date') > a.get('date')){
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    };
    this.sort();
},

byCompany: function(){
    this.comparator = function(model) {
        return model.get('company');
    }
    this.sort();
}

});
```

The View

```
var TicketView = Backbone.View.extend({
template: Handlebars.compile(
    '<div class="sort">' +
        '<a class="sortByDate">Sort By Date</a>' +
        '<a class="sortByCompany">Sort By Company</a>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="filter">' +
        '<a class="allTickets">All Tickets</a>' +
        '<a class="myTickets mid-link">My Tickets</a>' +
        '<a class="completedTickets">Completed Tickets</a>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<ul>'+
    '{{#each models}}<li class="ticket">' +                 
    '<div class="date">{{attributes.date}}</div>' +
    '<div class="name">{{attributes.name}}</div>' +
    '<div class="company-name">{{attributes.company}}</div>' +
    '</li>{{/each}}'+
    '</ul>'     
),

initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo(this.collection, "reset", this.render);
    this.listenTo(this.collection, "add", this.render);
    this.listenTo(this.collection, "remove", this.render);
    this.listenTo(this.collection, "change", this.render);

    this.listenTo(this.collection, "sort", this.render);
},

render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.collection));
    this.delegateEvents({
        'click .sortByDate': 'sortByDate',
        'click .sortByCompany': 'sortByCompany',
        'click .myTickets': 'myTickets',
        'click .completedTickets': 'completedTickets',
        'click .allTickets': 'allTickets'
    });
    return this;
},

sortByDate: function(){
    this.collection.byDate();
},

sortByCompany: function(){
    this.collection.byCompany();
},

myTickets: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.collection.byFilter("user", "Edd N.")));
},

completedTickets: function() {      
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.collection.byFilter("status", "Completed")));
},

allTickets: function(){
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.collection));
}

});
```

I believe that the code does not allow sorting of the filtered collection because these methods are attributed to the original collection whilst the filtered collection is a new instantiation of "Tickets" and cannot make use of these methods, possibly because it does not have the correct event listeners.

I have made numerous attempts to achieve the desired sorting by making a reference to the original collection and creating a separate collection for the filtered tickets and then attempting to call the sort methods on the new collection but have had no success. I have also attempted to create another view and pass the filtered collection into that view with the event listeners looking for events on the filtered collection.

The code above is stripped back from all of my attempts, but I hope it demonstrates what I want to achieve and I appreciate any help with this.

Thanks in advance, Edd Neal.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11886628/backbone-js-correct-way-of-filtering-a-collection/11887115#11887115

Comment: Your code works, check out the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9Aqq3/

Comment: Thanks for your help Mark but I am trying to achieve both sorting and filtering to give sorting of the filtered collection. So after the user has clicked my tickets and they receive the filtered collection(of just two items) if they were to click sortbydate now it would sort the two items by date rather than showing the overall collection sorted by date. Apologies if this was not clear in my description but thanks again.